# How To Move UIImageView?

Tags: animation, uiimageview, ipad, nstimer

Heres the deal:
I code an UIImageView in the viewDidLoad and i want it to move down with my fonction buttonPressed** without creating an other subview like i do.

Heres the code.

-(void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

banetteImage = [UIImage  imageNamed:@"myBanette.png"];

```
UIImageView *banetteView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:banetteImage];
banetteView.frame = CGRectMake(100, -740, 568, 790);
banetteView.opaque = NO;
```

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.5 target:self selector:@selector(buttonPressed: ) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

```
[self.view addSubview:banetteView];
```

}

-(void)buttonPressed {

```
double speed = 1 / round(random() % 100) + 1.0;

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:banetteView];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 2*speed ];

banetteView.frame = CGRectMake(100, -2, 568, 790);
banetteView.opaque = NO;

UIImageView *banetteView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:banetteImage];
banetteView2.frame = CGRectMake(100, -740, 568, 790);
banetteView.opaque = NO;
banetteView.hidden = YES;
[self.view addSubview:banetteView];

// set a stop callback so we can cleanup the banette when it reaches the
// end of its animation
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(onAnimationComplete:finished:context:)];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

}

-(void)onAnimationComplete:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context {

```
UIImageView *banetteView = context;


double speed = 1 / round(random() % 100) + 1.0;
banetteView.frame = CGRectMake(100, -2, 568, 790);
banetteView2.opaque = NO;
[self.view addSubview:banetteView2];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:banetteView];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 2*speed ];


[banetteView release];
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I found by adapting this code

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-sdk-learning-about-touch-events-basic-game-animation/